# Doxygen, Macros and Directories

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some code in C++ where I use a macro for the class definitions. Doxygen fails to resolve this properly.

I am using Doxygen 1.9.3.

The configuration file differences to default are:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = h=C++ cpp=C++
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = yes
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.cpp *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
```

The code example consists of three files:

Interfaces/IMetaObject.h:

```
class IMetaObject
{
    virtual ~IMetaObject() {};
    virtual const char* GetType() const = 0;
    virtual const std::vector<const char *>& GetInterfaces() const = 0;
    virtual const bool IsInterface(const char *) const = 0;
};
```

Interfaces/MetaObject.h:

```
#include "IMetaObject.h"

#define MetaObjectClass(className, interfaceName) \
namespace kia{ constexpr char class_##className[] = #className; } \
class className : public  MetaObject<kia::class_##className>, virtual public interfaceName \
{ \
    AddInterface(MetaObject, interfaceName::Name)

template<const char* type_name>
class MetaObject  :  public virtual IMetaObject
{
public:
    MetaObject() {}
    virtual ~MetaObject() {};

    virtual const char* GetType() const override
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    virtual const std::vector<const char*>& GetInterfaces() const override
    {
        return _interfaces;
    }

    virtual const bool IsInterface(const char* interface) const override
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

and Modules/Modul.h:

```
#include "MetaObject.h"
#include "Instances.h"


MetaObjectClass(Modul, IModul)
public:

    Modul(){}

    virtual ~Modul()
    {
    }

};
```

The *class Modul* is not recognized by doxygen, which is obvious in the class hierarchy diagram.

When I move the code from the subdirectories to the main directory, everything works. This is good for a workaround, but - how can I tell doxygen to resolve the macros properly in case of subdirectories?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are the settings in your doxygen settings file different from the default settings (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: Especially important is the setting of `MACRO_EXPANSION` in your case.

Comment: Most likely you need to set `INCLUDE_PATH=interfaces`. Please also show the "class hierarchy diagram" you see and the page where you see it. Note the current doxygen version is 1.9.6